# How to hookup pt100 with pi 3 without max31865 for temperature logging

Tags: pi-3, gpio, temperature

Absolutely noon on pi here.

I wanted to make a temperature logger with my raspberry Pi 3 and a "pt100 2 wire k type" thermocouple. I spent the evening googling about it and learned that one of the best way to do this would be through a max13865 board that communicates between the sensor and the board. But I'm for India and the board is exorbitantly costly to import and fakes on Amazon site has very poor review.

I also noticed there's a simpler approach discussed in raspberry help for DS18B20, which is a 3 wire configuration.

My question: 
1. Is it possible to wire my 2 wire pt 100 to the pi3 without the max13865 in the middle? If yes can anyone help me with the wiring diagram..
2. I'm trying to measure temperature between -70°c to 100°c. So will the waterproof DS18B20 work in such range?

Thanks.

Comment: Hello and welcome. "pt100 2 wire k type" thermocouple seems to be mixing up two things -> PT 100 vs. thermocouple, please specify which it is. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for responding. The unit I have is in the line of this. https://m.aliexpress.com/item/32501249052.html?trace=wwwdetail2mobilesitedetail&productId=32501249052&productSubject=K-PT100-type-Temperture-sensor-2-wires-thermocouple-for-gas-stove-china-supplier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Connecting a PT100 directly**

Well, the PT100 is simply a resistor, reading it requires driving a constant current through it and measuring the voltage accross it. To do so one typically uses an ADC - analogue-to-digital converter - which the Pi does not have included.

While there is a way to read a resistor with the digital input/output of the Pi - as explained here: [pigpio - Example LDR](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/ex_LDR.html) - I doubt it'll be as accurate as is required to properly read a PT100 resistance thermometer. At 20°C the change in resistance is about 2 Ohms / 5 K (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistance_thermometer#Temperature-dependent_resistances_for_various_popular_resistance_thermometers)); whereas the change of resistance of the LDR in the example is multiple orders of magnitue (1 MOhm to 2-4 KOhm).

<sub><sup>Note that the above is with respect to a PT100 resistor not a type K thermocouple. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistance_thermometer#Advantages_and_limitations) for differences between resistance thermometers and thermocouples.</sup></sub>

**DS18B20**

According to this [datasheet](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Temp/DS18B20.pdf) the DS18B20 measures temperatures from -55°C to
+125°C. So that would not be in the specified range. Note that an accuracy of ±0.5°C in the range from -10°C to +85°C is listed - which suggests that accuracy will be worse outside that range.

Comment: Thanks I guess this is the best answer I can get.. I'll go back and re-evaluate my options